# Can't update file

Tags: r, unix, gdata, xls

I have this problem: I create a script in R that open a file xls in unix (I use read.xls from gdata) and it works, but if I open that file from windows I can't update it because "another user" is using that file. I couldn't find a function that "close" the connection to the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: this is a common problem (feature) with Windows files/software. If you open a MS Word document, and then try to use the fileExplorer to delete the file, you'll get the same message. Probably Windows "sees" that R is using the file. Still just getting into R myself. Does `close(con)` help? (using, of course, your name for `con`). Good luck.

Comment: read.xls from gdata has not a close(con)!
I think that is only a connection problem, infact if I wait, sometimes several minutes, it works as usual.
Thank you